# Serial Port read failure: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)

Tags: serial, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been using rosserial connect to Mbed and the node was working well, and recently there was a few times of software update. After the update I cannot run the node and it give the following information. My Mbed was operating well and the I am currently using Ubuntu14.04  ros indigo

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1445252210.206610] ROS Serial Python Node

[INFO] [WallTime: 1445252210.216847] Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud

[WARN] [WallTime: 1445252212.329202] Serial Port read failure: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)

[INFO] [WallTime: 1445252212.329920] Packet Failed :  Failed to read msg data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ju/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/nodes/serial_node.py", line 82, in <module>
    client.run()
  File "/home/ju/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 472, in run
    rospy.loginfo("msg len is %d",len(msg))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'msg' referenced before assignment
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219394/serial-port-read-failure:-device-reports-readiness-to-read-but-returned-no-data-(device-disconnected?)/) by [Ju Wen Bo](https://answers.ros.org/users/24626/ju-wen-bo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-10-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just had the same result. And it was working on this computer a few weeks before.
It seems unrelated to rosserial package: [Ubuntu bug ticket](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1501240)

Downgrade to 3.13.0-62-generic and it should work.

---

Originally posted by [vmatos](https://answers.ros.org/users/17756/vmatos/) with karma: 124 on 2015-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0